# How can I convert JSON to key value strings for POST

Tags: java, php

I currently have a PHP page, that I need to port over so that it runs through Java instead of PHP.  Part of that conversion requires running a Sha1 conversion onto a string generated by PHP's [http-build-query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)  I need to get the exact same string output in Java that PHP would generate.

So for example:

I have a complex JSON object. (syntax is not exact)

```
{"user":{"name:'Bob Smith',
         "age":47,
         "sex":'M',
              'dob':'5/12/1956'},
              'pastimes'['golf', 'opera', 'poker', 'rap'),
              'children'['bobby':{'age':12,'sex':'M'},
                                'sally'{'age':8, 'sex':'F'}],
              'CEO'}};
```

I need to convert it to a keyvalue string such as

```
user%5Bname%5D=Bob+Smith&user%5Bage%5D=47&user%5Bsex%5D=M&
user%5Bdob%5D=5%2F12%2F1956&pastimes%5B0%5D=golf&pastimes%5B1%5D=opera&
pastimes%5B2%5D=poker&pastimes%5B3%5D=rap&children%5Bbobby%5D%5Bage%5D=12&
children%5Bbobby%5D%5Bsex%5D=M&children%5Bsally%5D%5Bage%5D=8&
children%5Bsally%5D%5Bsex%5D=F&flags_0=CEO
```

Essentially, I need to do what the [http-build-query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) in PHP does with complex arrays.

Comment: You're sending from **Java** code to PHP? Not from *JavaScript* code to PHP?

Comment: I'm sending from JAVA, mimicing a call that is currently being sent from PHP.
I need the string to be exactly the same because it goes through a Sha1 conversion.